# how to automatically refresh iframe angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

This is code (Use Angularjs and server run localhost )

index.html

```
<iframe src="{{Url}}" width="100%" height="500"></iframe>
```

app.js

```
$scope.Url = "http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html";
```

**Need to refresh every 30 second** 
How can ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the $timeout feature.  Set an initial value then every 30 seconds call the reload function and increment a query string so that you don't have a caching problem.  If that is not an issue, you can remove that $scope.seed stuff.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('UrlController', UrlController);

UrlController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];

function UrlController($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.loadingCounter = 0;

    $scope.seed = getUtcDate().getTime();
    //adding the counter so the url reload isn't cached.
    $scope.baseUrl = 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html';

    $scope.Url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html';

    $scope.getReloadUrl = getReloadUrl;
    $scope.onReload = onReload;

    function onReload() {
        $scope.loadingCounter++;
        $scope.Url = $scope.getReloadUrl();
        //restart it again.
        $timeout($scope.onReload, 30000);
    }

    function getReloadUrl(){
        //create a unique query string
        var reloadId = $scope.seed + $scope.loadingCounter;
        return $scope.baseUrl + '?reloadId=' + reloadId;
    }

    //start it up
    $scope.onReload();

    //helper function 
    function getUtcDate() {
        var now = new Date();
        var nowUtc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
        return nowUtc;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Javascript with setInterval to refresh the src of the Source...

```
<script>
window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();", 30000);

function reloadIFrame() {
 document.frames["frameNameHere"].location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer

Comment: But I am waiting answer with angularjs